# Driver class naming convention in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I couldn't get my head around Orchard documentation and this is yet another that makes my head spin.

I have a Widget of type "Product List", and have the title "Featured Slider". How should I name my Driver then? Is it Widget_Product_List? Widget_Featured_Slider? Or should it be something else.

I've seen [Shape](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes#Wrappers) naming convention in the docs, but not for Driver or Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

The convention for drivers is to name them by the name of the part followed by the word Driver. For example, if your part is named ProductPart, the driver would be ProductPartDriver. You should take a look at some existing drivers.

Widget_Product_List would look more like the name of a shape.

Comment: So this implies that driver classes are only for parts, and not shapes, then?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "for" here. A driver is associated to a part, but some of its methods create shapes.